# og:video and thumbnail size in Timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

What I have to do to have a thumbnail of a video in player's size - just like Youtube has?

[image]

I've copied almost every Open Graph metatags:

```html
<meta property="og:title" content="Lloyd - Be The One ft. Trey Songz, Young Jeezy">
<meta property="og:description" content="Music video by Lloyd performing Be The One. (C) 2011 Interscope Records">
<meta property="og:type" content="video">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://i4.ytimg.com/vi/cLwnojWx0Ac/hqdefault.jpg">
<meta property="og:video" content="http://www.youtube.com/v/cLwnojWx0Ac?version=3&amp;autohide=1">
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash">
<meta property="og:video:width" content="398">
<meta property="og:video:height" content="224">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="YouTube">
```

I've left only og:url tag. But it still does not work property.

Answer (score 0):

Its a facebook Bug,

Here the links to the officeal bugtracker

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/210393579041715

and

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/197191103695468